# SSD Storage Giving Problems

Tags: disk-utility, partition, ssd

This is actually not a recent thing, a couple of years ago, I temporarily installed Kali Linux on a separate partition on the SSD. When I then deleted Kali Linux, I found out that the partitions never sort of merged (I guess that's the right term). When I go to Disk Utility, I see the following information:

[image: The original SSD with the 250+GB storage.]

[image: The child container underneath with the 125GB storage capacity.]

[image: Another child of the disk1 container.]

What I'm wondering is if there's anyway to have the Apple OS and all the storage go back to the original 251GB maximum? Where is that other 125GB of storage? There's no information on the laptop that's vital, so anything that would require a reset is fine.

**Edit: Tried the resizecontainer command in terminal, failed result: 
Started APFS operation
Error: -69743: The new size must be different than the existing size**

**Results of list:**
[image]

Comment: Try `sudo diskutil apfs resizecontainer /dev/disk1 0` from terminal to expand container to use all available space.  If that doesn't work (perhaps old partition still exists) then update question with results of `diskutil list`.

Comment: @lx07 Tried it out, updated question with appropriate results, error message and picture of `diskutil list`.

Comment: do you have a time machine backup?  I'd boot to recovery mode, wipe everything, and restore from backup

Comment: Take a look with `sudo gpt show disk 0` - you'll probably see the free space is *before* the container not *after*.  If so backup/restore as @MatthewBarclay says would be easiest.

Comment: Edit your question and add the output from the commands `diskutil info disk0s1 | grep -e Offset -e Size` and `diskutil info disk0s2 | grep -e Offset -e Size`. Basically, I am trying to determine if the free space occurs before or after the macOS partition.